# Does it make sense to run more executors than number of partitions?

Tags: apache-spark

I execute process with some data on Apache Spark and data is splitted into 22 partitions. Does it make sens to run it on more than 22 executors?

EDIT:
Above I used shorthand. I have in mind executors * cores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided by Ram is correct, I just wanted to explain a bit more why you should do as he says.

When you run a spark job you will have n x m threads that are able to execute your query based on the physcal plan over your partitioned data. Now each thread at one point in time will compute tasks over one partition.

If you have in total 10 executors and 2 cores per executor you will have 20 threads which means 20 tasks will run in parallel. If you have 22 partitions, 2 partitions will wait for first available core in order to resume.

This means that if you have less cores some tasks will have to wait. But this is a desidered behavior since we know that for some operations keys are not uniformly distributed. That means that some partitions will take longer to compute and other will take less.

Taking this into account, dont blindly put 2-3 times the number of threads you have to be the partitioning size, evaluate what the run times of tasks in stages are and you will see how many tasks are deviating from the mean run time. Also too few partitions can lead to memory overflow, too many partitions can lead to scheduling overhead.

Edit: to complete the repartition advice, in case you are performing joins on skewed keys and you cannot broadcast, repartition wont help you. Repartition is useful for ensuring uniform distribution of data only in case of narrow operations.

Comment: okey, I understand, but... What happens if I have more threads than partitions?

Comment: They will remain unused, there is no work for them. you can wrap actions in Future and then run spark actions in parallel in different pools if you have resources to spare.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, you shoud NOT use number of executors which are equivalent to number of partitons...

Lets suppose you have 1000 partitions, from your logic you need to assign 1000 executors to process 1000 partitions which is wrong.

In your case described in the post.... Your partition number could be/should be equivalent to

`number executors * number of cores * 2-3`

For example your number of executors = 5
each exector has 4 cores then you should go with this.

Note : make sure that you have almost equal sized partitions to ensure uniform distribuation of data using `repartition` or `coalesce` based on your use case.

Comment: Sorry, I used shorthand. I have in mind exactly executors * cores